# Codeigniter text email formatting

Tags: codeigniter, email, text

I want to send email of type: text from web app made in codeigniter. I don't want to use html email, because I have read a lot of articles against them.

And my question is, if there is any way how to make letters in body of email bold and if it is possible to use bullets somehow even when I want to post email of type text.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way to bold plain text (seems obvious to me) but you can use any format you want to work around it, like `*asterisks for important text*`. For bullets, you can use dashes or dot characters like `·`.

> · Item 1
>   · Item 2

However, you can send both an HTML and plaintext message at once. Users who can view HTML email will get the formatted version, while everyone else will get the plaintext version.

> http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html
>
> `$this->email->set_alt_message()`
>
> Sets the alternative email message body:
>
> `$this->email->set_alt_message('This is the alternative message');`
>
> This
>   is an optional message string which can be used if you send HTML
>   formatted email. It lets you specify an alternative message with no
>   HTML formatting which is added to the header string for people who do
>   not accept HTML email. If you do not set your own message CodeIgniter
>   will extract the message from your HTML email and strip the tags.

For things like newsletters, it's also common to provide a link to a hosted HTML version of the email message.

> I don't want to use html email, because I have read a lot of articles against them.

I'd guess that those articles are antiquated by now, HTML email is quite common and should be safe to use as most email clients can display HTML.